# Can I parallel two TP4056s to charge 1 cell?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, parallel, lithium, tp4056

I have a 3600 mAh Li-ion battery and I want charge it at 2 A. I want to use a TP4056 module but its output current is 1 A max.

So I decided to use 2 modules in parallel like I drew in the picture. Is this possible? Is there any problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other than one module sending false voltage signals to other hence confusing it as Battery Voltage, I don't see a problem but I would rather use cheap diy powerbank circuit instead, they mostly charge around 2Amps,

Or better just use a single module and wait a little longer.

Comment: but this module works in cc mode and so it's impossible that one module send wrong voltage to another module.output voltage of both modules sets by battery impedance.

Comment: True if real world components were all ideal and same but there are always minor to massive differences and imperfections, If you make this circuit you will most probably notice this phenomena because one of the circuits will show battery full indicator (blue light) earlier than other.

Comment: if one module shows full battery then it's output goes disconnect while another module still pumps current that goes into battery not another module until it shows full battery too.so i didn'd see any problem here

Comment: It should still charge your battery at twice the current fine will battery is low, when battery is almost fully charged, they should both go into CV mode from CC but one of the modules will say battery is fully charged because other module is pumping current into the battery required by first module to detect if battery is fully charged or worse, both can turn off earlier (very minor chance)